# Converting safeFrame tag into javaScript code and load it in .js file just like one file?

Tags: javascript, html, google-publisher-tag

I've written my safeFrame tag to render in a .html page when called from the browser. This is working fine, however when I am trying to convert the .html file into .js file I am also convering the content of the .html file i.e. my safeFrame tag in javaScript language too.

However the challenge I am facing is that when I am converting the safeFrame tag into a .js file and trying to render it through

I am watching an error. I know a safeFrame can't be loaded inside another safeFrame, however in this case trying to load the safeFrame through a .js file doesn't mean its creating a frame.

Can anyone help me here?